# Is there pandas functionality to grab specific timestamps from a datetime column on a daily basis?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have dataset of ticker information with timestamps spanning over a month, but I need to grab only the times at 4:00PM. The closest tick to this is 16:00:03, which is what I currently use. I hard coded the vales for the month of August by manually inputting the dates, but would like to change this so I can specify what month to use instead of inputting every day, or setting a start and end date.

```
df = df.loc[((df["timestamp"] == "2021-08-02 16:00:03")) | 
           ((df["timestamp"] == "2021-08-03 16:00:03")) |
           ((df["timestamp"] == "2021-08-04 16:00:03")) |
           ((df["timestamp"] == "2021-08-05 16:00:03")) |
           ((df["timestamp"] == "2021-08-06 16:00:03")) ]
```

```
    timestamp           bidprice    askprice
0   2021-08-02 14:59:03 99.937500   99.949219
1   2021-08-02 15:00:03 99.941406   99.945312
2   2021-08-02 15:01:03 99.941406   99.945312
3   2021-08-02 15:02:03 99.941406   99.945312
4   2021-08-02 15:03:03 99.941406   99.945312
...
        timestamp           bidprice    askprice
468109  2021-09-01 22:55:02 110.500000  110.546875
468110  2021-09-01 22:56:02 110.500000  110.546875
468111  2021-09-01 22:57:02 110.500000  110.546875
468112  2021-09-01 22:58:02 110.484375  110.531250
468113  2021-09-01 22:59:02 110.484375  110.531250
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) merge with a DataFrame that is a single Series with daily times at 16:00:00. You can specify the direction to be `'nearest'`, `'forward'` or `'backward'` to get the matching logic you'd like.

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 30000
np.random.seed(123)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': (pd.date_range('2021-08-01', freq='29s', periods=N)
                                  + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.normal(0,1,N), unit='ms')),
                    'value': range(N)})
```

#### Code

```
#Daily 16:00:00 DataFrame
start_date = '2021-08-01 16:00:00'
end_date = '2021-08-11 16:00:00'
dfbase = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')})

result = pd.merge_asof(dfbase, df1.sort_values('timestamp'), 
                       left_on='date', right_on='timestamp',
                       direction='nearest', allow_exact_matches=True)
```

---

```
print(result)

                  date                     timestamp  value
0  2021-08-01 16:00:00 2021-08-01 15:59:53.999784590   1986
1  2021-08-02 16:00:00 2021-08-02 16:00:14.000160424   4966
2  2021-08-03 16:00:00 2021-08-03 16:00:05.000322262   7945
3  2021-08-04 16:00:00 2021-08-04 15:59:55.998303052  10924
4  2021-08-05 16:00:00 2021-08-05 15:59:46.998877694  13903
5  2021-08-06 16:00:00 2021-08-06 16:00:06.998954204  16883
6  2021-08-07 16:00:00 2021-08-07 15:59:58.000602203  19862
7  2021-08-08 16:00:00 2021-08-08 15:59:49.001400290  22841
8  2021-08-09 16:00:00 2021-08-09 16:00:08.998636467  25821
9  2021-08-10 16:00:00 2021-08-10 15:59:59.998385577  28800
10 2021-08-11 16:00:00 2021-08-11 01:39:31.001659917  29999
```

---

Another option, that will give you a similar result as above but less information is to use `DataFrame.asof` after setting the index. You can supply the Series of daily dates.

```
df1 = df1.set_index('timestamp')
df1.asof(dfbase.date)

                       value
date                        
2021-08-01 16:00:00   1986.0
2021-08-02 16:00:00   4965.0
2021-08-03 16:00:00   7944.0
2021-08-04 16:00:00  10924.0
2021-08-05 16:00:00  13903.0
2021-08-06 16:00:00  16882.0
2021-08-07 16:00:00  19862.0
2021-08-08 16:00:00  22841.0
2021-08-09 16:00:00  25820.0
2021-08-10 16:00:00  28800.0
2021-08-11 16:00:00  29999.0
```

So similar result (some rows are different because this enforces the `'backward'` direction for the match), but doesn't give you any information about which exact timestamp was matched, and also doesn't support setting a `tolerance` to exclude bad matches (possibly like the last row which is still the closest, but is a bad match)

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to convert the DateTime strings to timestamps

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Then isolate

```py
df = df.loc[df['timestamp'] == datetime.time(hour=16, minute=3)]
```

Sorry for my untested code but this should at least put you on the right track.